# Using JetPack Room as in-memory cache for sharing state in multiple activity

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm now trying to implement sharing states (e.g like in twitter) in multiple activity. For example sharing the like state in list activity and also in detail activity.

My idea so far is to return LiveData from repository and subscribe it in both activity which looks like in memory cache implemented using LiveData. Repository will be like below. (This is not a real code but I guess it is easy to imagine how it works)

```
class PostRepository {
  val postCache : MutableLiveData<List<Post>> = MutableLiveData()

  fun getAll(): List<Post> {
    val posts = source.getAll() // source is something like api or real db
    postCache.value = posts
    return posts
  }

  fun like(id: String){
    postCache.value.map { post ->
      if(post.id == id){
        post.like = true
      }
    }

    source.like(id)
  }
}
```

When I find in-memory db for Room in Room's document (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Room#inmemorydatabasebuilder), I though it might be good to use Room in-memory db as a cache since it can return LiveData and also can notify when db is updated. But in the document, it looks like in-memory db is just for testing.

So my question is, is Room in-memory db might be a good solution to implement cache? And if not, is there better way than having LiveData object.

Answer (score -1):

Bingo! I have the same thought too, LOL.
In my opinion, a shorter way for a hit of a cache will be better in performance.
Get the hit of caches from an in-memory db,mm...which still has a lot of things to do.But for just check the business logics on testing which is not better performance required.
Hope above helps.

[github.com/halohoop](https://github.com/halohoop)